# Передать функцию как аргумент, затем использовать как метод класса

Tags: c++

Требуется передать функцию аргументом для другой функции, затем сделать переданную функцию методом класса. Пытался сделать примерно так:

```
class A{
    public:
        void setExDef(std::function<void()> *f){
            exDef = f;
        };
    
        void executeDef(){
            exDef();
        };
    
    private:
        void *exDef;
};
```

Затем получил ошибку `error: expression cannot be used as a function`.
Надеюсь что пояснил понятно.

Comment: вы понимаете, что ваш exDef есть  void *?  И как по вашему компилятор должен понимать  void*( )? От того что вы присвоили функцию  void указателю, этот указатель не стал указателем на функцию, а наоборот . И зачем вам  void *? Просто храните std::function<void()> и передайте его не по указателю. А ваша функция будет иметь тип  void() или она может быть любая?...

Comment: *сделать переданную функцию методом класса* — что вы на самом деле хотите? Ну никак "сделать методом" (читай: функцией-членом) свободную функцию невозможно. Вызвать из функции-члена — дело другое...

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, вам надо

```
class A{
    public:
        void setExDef(std::function<void()> f){
            exDef = std::move(f);
        };
    
        void executeDef(){
            exDef();
        };
    
    private:
        std::function<void()> exDef;
};
```

Ну, или

```
class A{
    public:
        void setExDef(void(*f)()){
            exDef = f;
        };
    
        void executeDef(){
            exDef();
        };
    
    private:
        void (*exDef)();
};
```

Comment: Ещё лучше было бы объявить через `typedef` свой тип для функции, и использовать его и для параметра метода setExDef и для члена exDef

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Так можно наплодить слишком много typedef'ов. Мне это не кажется касивым.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat А зачем тут `move`? Разве он дает какую-то выгоду в данном случае?

Comment: `std::function` может выделять память в куче, если функтор большой.